# HMVC CodeIgniter view igniter type="date" not working on html

Tags: php, html, css, date, codeigniter-3

am making this form input in my HMVC project. i want to have

```
input type="date"
```

but it happens to be the output was just like a normal textbox. what other ways can i do this or what is the error?

add_view.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/bootstrap/css/inputfield.css">
<html>
<div>
    <fieldset>


            <?php

                echo form_open('Clients/create');
            ?>

            <p>
                <label class="field" for=""><span>*</span>Name:</label>
                <input type = "text" name="" class ="textbox-300">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label class="field" for=""><span>*</span>Details:</label>
                <textarea name=""></textarea>
            </p>
        </br></br></br>
            <p>
                <label class="field" for=""><span>*</span>Address:</label>
                <textarea name=""></textarea>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label class="field" for=""><span>*</span>Contact Number:</label>
                <input type = "text" name="" class ="textbox-300">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label class="field" for=""><span>*</span>Contact Email:</label>
                <input type = "text" name="" class ="textbox-300">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label class="field" for=""><span>*</span>Date Added:</label>
                <input type="date" name="" min="1950-01-01">
            </p>


            <?php
                echo form_submit('submit','Save');
                echo validation_errors();
                echo form_close();
            ?>


    </fieldset>
</div>
</html>
```

inputfield.css

```
textarea {
    width: 51%;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    resize: none;
    float:right;
}

fieldset {
    width: 500px;
}

label .field{

    text-align:left;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    font-weight: bold;
}

input.textbox-300{
    width:350;
    float:right;
}

fieldset p {

    clear:both;
    padding:5px;
}

label span, .required{
    color:red;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.center {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

im sorry im not good in this date thing so please help me

Comment: where is name=""??? and do u want date format???

Comment: i want to do something like this http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_date i have done it before in my mvc project. but as of my hmvc its just like a blank textbox.

Comment: yes just because of `<input type="date" name="" min="1950-01-01">` use name attribute as `<input type="date" name="yourDate" min="1950-01-01">`

Comment: still not the date picker. :(

Comment: r u using date picker js library?

Comment: i think not? how can i use it? and also i cannot do any type="type" functions. maybe the solution is near?

Comment: `print_r($_POST);` what are u getting in this?

Comment: i am not entering any of this data yet. i just need to have the box that have the date picker just like in the w3schools example.

Comment: date picker appears to be blank because it is not supported by mozilla fire fox. if theres any that mozilla supports please let me know. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104976/discussion-between-devpro-and-kev-m).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting empty `textbox` result because you are not using `name` attribute in your input fields just add `name` attribute in all input fields as:

**Example:**

```
<input type = "text" name="yourName" class ="textbox-300">
<textarea name="Details"></textarea>
<textarea name="Address"></textarea>
<input type = "text" name="ContactNo" class ="textbox-300">
<input type = "text" name="Email" class ="textbox-300">
<input type="date" name="YourDate" min="1950-01-01">
```

Comment: still it does not output datepicker

Answer (score 0):

date picker appears to be blank because it is not supported by mozilla fire fox. if theres any that mozilla supports please let me know. thanks